# Need some understanding the docker run command

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am starting docker registry by follwoing the below URL from Docker website "https://docs.docker.com/registry/" .

To start the Regsistry they suggested below command:

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2`

Here for the above using the help i could understand the meaning of few arguments:

1. `-d` --> Run container in background and print container ID
2. `-p` --> Publish a container’s port(s) to the host
3. `--name` --> Assign a name to the container

So here whats is meaning or relavance of the argument "**registry:2**"

Comment: It is nothing but the docker `registry` image tagged `2`. As you are trying to run the registry as docker container. See https://hub.docker.com/_/registry and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registry:2` is the name of the image you need to create the container you named `registry`, where `registry` is the image id and `2` is the version you want.

Please look at [Docker hub registry page](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry).